# post request using JAX-RS client with no Payload but content-Type specified

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

I am getting a inputStream from http with no payload but content-Type set.I want to send this inputStream to another servlet.The code is as follows:-

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
Invocation.Builder builder = client.target(url).request();
Response response = builder.post(Entity.entity(inputStream, contentType));
```

Doing this throws an error

```
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IllegalStateException invoking http://192.168.7.2:8181/url: Already connected
```

But if i try with the inputStream having payload ,the code works fine.
I am using apache-CXF and JAX-RS.

Is there any work Around ?

Comment: Why cant one empty string be posted?